# Mesh fuses together when touching another mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to build a tiny bedroom in Blender and I was working on modeling a closet when I noticed this "problem/bug".

In the exact moment a mesh touches another mesh, it automatically fuses together. So when I try to move one of this meshes, it moves everything. I don't really know how to unlink it. Is there an option I accidentally enabled?

I appreciate any kind of feedback!

[Video](https://youtu.be/AXjnq0Fs-9A)

Comment: You have proportional editing turned on (white dot on top toolbar). Either click the dot or press 'O' to disable it.

Comment: Aaah thank you! I thought the proportional editing was just for modeling when Edit Mode is active, didn't know it also worked when being in Object Mode. Thanks again ^^

Comment: Normally I wouldn't expect it to affect Object mode, but something in your scene is obviously affecting things.

Comment: Since you can enable it in _Object Mode_, it can of course be used in _Object Mode_ as well. From the _Blender Manual: "Proportional Editing is typically used in Edit Mode, however, it can also be used in Object Mode. In Object Mode the tool works on entire objects rather than individual mesh components."_

Comment: Oh that's nice to know! Thanks you two :)